# How to update existing object with additional data

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, mongoose

The project is created with nodejs and mongoose. What I am trying to do is to update the existing model with addition data (which is a comment, in that case).

This is the model and its methods:

```js
const bugSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    time: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    assignedTo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    assignedBy: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    priority: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    comments: {
        comment:[
            {
                user:{
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                },
                content: {
                    type: String,
                    required: true
                }
            }
        ]
    }

});

bugSchema.methods.addComment = function(comment){
    const username = comment.user;
    const content = comment.content;
    console.log(comment);
    const updatedComments = [...this.comments];
    updatedComments.push({
       user : username,
       content: content
    });
    this.comments = updatedComments;
    return this.save();

};
```

The controller, which is passing the information from the form:

```js
exports.postComment =  (req,res,next) =>{
    const bugId = req.body.bugID;
    const name = req.session.user.fullName;
    const content = req.body.content;
    const prod = {name, content};

    Bug.findById(bugId).then(bug =>{
        return bug.addComment(prod);
    })
        .then(result =>{
            console.log(result);
        });


};
```

I am getting a following error:

```js
(node:3508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.comments is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(node:3508) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: this.comments is not iterable
```

The error indicate you're trying to iterable a type of data which does NOT has that capability.

You can check that printing the type:

```
console.log(typeof this.comments)
```

Or even, priting the whole object:

```
console.log(this.comments)
```

as you can see, in both cases you're getting an object, not a list (how you spect)

So you can do 2 things:

1- **Iterable a list**

*this.comments* is an object but into that object you have the list you want, so just use the list instead.

```
bugSchema.methods.addComment = function(comment){
    const username = comment.user;
    const content = comment.content;
    console.log(comment);
    //const updatedComments = [...this.comments];
    const updatedComments = [...this.comments.comment];
    updatedComments.push({
       user : username,
       content: content
    });
    this.comments = updatedComments;
    return this.save();
};
```

Or you can modify your schema making the comments a list instead of an object

2- **comments as list in schema**

Define the comments attribute as a list

```
const bugSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    ...
    ...,
    comments:[
        {
            user:{
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            content: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

And then, try to iterable it as how you been doing

```
bugSchema.methods.addComment = function(comment){
    const username = comment.user;
    const content = comment.content;
    console.log(comment);
    const updatedComments = [...this.comments];
    updatedComments.push({
       user : username,
       content: content
    });
    this.comments = updatedComments;
    return this.save();

};
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but comments is an object and not an array so you can't push using [...this.comments] and I think it is the comment you want to push?

```
const updatedComments = [...this.comment];
updatedComments.push({
   user : username,
   content: content
});
this.comment = updatedComments;
```

Answer (score 1):

From your schema comments is not an array. you are trying to spread an object into an array. `const updatedComments = [...this.comments];` also push works on array.
try to modify your schema definitions by declaring the commentSchema outside the bugSchema.

```html
const commentSchema = new Schema({
     user:{
            type: String,
            required: true
      },
      content: {
            type: String,
            required: true
      }
})


const bugSchema = new Schema({
  
  comments: {
    type: [commentSchema]
  }

})
```

```html
Bug.findByIdAndUpdate(bugId, {$push: {comments: newComment}})
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `findByIdAndUpdate` Mongoose method, you better use `save`

it is written here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html

`The findOneAndUpdate() function in Mongoose has a wide variety of use cases. You should use save() to update documents where possible, but there are some cases where you need to use findOneAndUpdate(). In this tutorial, you'll see how to use findOneAndUpdate(), and learn when you need to use it.`

Below a router example

```
router.put('/items', (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body._id || !req.body.title) {
    return res.status(501).send({ message: 'Missing parameters, or incorrect parameters' });
  }

  return itemModel.findOne({ _id: req.body._id }, (err, item) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({
        message: err
      });
    }

    item.title = req.body.title; // <------------- You rewrite what was before stored on title attribute

    return item.save((err, item) => { // <------------- You save it, this is not gonna create a new one, except if it doesn't exist already
      if (err) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          message: 'Failed to update item'
        });
      } else {
        return res.status(200).send({
          message: 'Item update succesfully',
          data: item
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```